# vsvim call to function not supported

Tags: visual-studio, vim, visual-studio-2019, vsvim

I wrote a function in my vimrc file:

```bash
function! InsertDebugBlock()
    call append(line('.'), [", "])
    call setline(line('.') + 1, '#if DEBUG')
    call setline(line('.') + 2, '#endif')
    normal j
    startinsert
endfunction
```

however, when I called it via vsvim in visual studio, it said:

> call to function InsertDebugBlock not supported

[image: call to function InsertDebugBlock not supported]

but it works well with gvim

[image: it works well with gvim]

here are some configurations in vsvim

[image: some configurations in vsvim]

it says my vimrc file is **"C:\Users\Deler\vimfiles\_vimrc"**, and that's what it is.

I can't find the problem. My vsvim version is **2.8.0.0**, visual studio 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***VsVim is not Vim so there is no reason whatsoever to expect anything from Vim to work in VsVim and vice-versa***.

Case in point: [here](https://github.com/VsVim/VsVim/blob/master/Documentation/Supported%20Features.md) is the very limited subset of features supported by VsVim and [here](https://github.com/VsVim/VsVim/blob/master/Documentation/Project%20Goals.md#vim-script--plugins) is the (very reasonable) rationale for not supporting vimscript.

Preliminary conclusion: VsVim doesn't support vimscript so there is no way to make your snippet work.

Now… as-is, your function can't do what you claim it to do in Vim anyway. It actually produces this when called with the cursor on `foo`:

```
foo
|#if DEBUG    # cursor before #if
#endif
```

Besides, using `setline()` the way you do anywhere else than the end of the buffer will inevitably result in loss of data:

```
# before
foo
bar
baz
quux

# after
foo
#if DEBUG    # oops! where is bar?
#endif
baz
quux
```

Not good.

Here is a simpler implementation that is guaranteed to work in Vim and, judging by the linked resources, is very likely to also work in VsVim:

```
nnoremap <key> o#ifdef DEBUG<CR>#endif<Esc>O
```

Use whatever `<key>` you want.